# Query-replace with some context checking?

Tags: latex, query-replace, isearch-filter-predicate

`(query-replace "foo" "bar")` shows you all occurrences of `foo` and offers to replace them by `bar`.

I would love to have a version of `query-replace` that only picks the occurrences of `foo` that are "in some context" (to be defined). At the moment, I'm thinking of LaTeX files with the context being "any part that is in math style". Or any part not in math style. These parts are already highlighted by Emacs' `latex-mode` so it can recognize them.

`query-replace` can already perform a bit of context checking since its `DELIMITED` argument allows restricting to occurrences surrounded by word boundaries, but this is a simple special case that can be implemented with regular expressions, e.g., looking for `\<foo\>`.

**My question:** do you know of an extension of `query-replace` in some package somewhere that can do the replace-only-in-math-style trick I need? Or of something similar enough that would be a good start for tweaking and hacking around?

Comment: I don't know any such tool, but if you want to write it you may want to give a look at [`texmathp.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=blob;f=texmathp.el;hb=HEAD) (it's bundled into AUCTeX but doesn't require it to work), which provides you the function `texmathp` to check whether point is inside math mode.

Comment: Thanks a million. I've followed your advice and looked at texmathp. It seems that I just have to make a copy of the original `query-replace` and insert a `(if (texmathp) ..)` at the right place. I'll try that and report on the outcome.

Comment: Now that I know about the `isearch-filter-predicate` variable I have set it to something that calls `texmathp`. It is annoying that they do not have the same interface: `isearch-filer-predicate` wants a `(beg end)` region argument, `texmathp` looks at point in buffer. I'd suggest just allowing an optional `pos` argument to `texmathp`.

Comment: @phs Did you manage to bind "`isearch-filter-predicate` to something that calls `texmathp`"? I am also interested in this approach.

Comment: @Gabriele. Yes, see my code at `http://www.lsv.fr/~phs/query-replace-in-tex-math-only.el`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  If you use libraries [**Isearch+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) and [**Zones**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Zones) (including optional library [`isearch-prop.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch-prop.el)), and you set option **`isearchp-query-replace-zones-flag.`** to non-`nil`, then replacement commands such as `query-replace` are limited to the buffer zones you define.

This works by binding `isearch-filter-predicate` to a function that recognizes the zones.

(Isearch works the same way - you can limit searching to defined zones.  And if you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can bookmark a set of zones.)

You can also query-replace (or search) the *complement* of a set of zones.  Toggle this behavior using `C-M-~` during Isearch.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the libraries and the explanations. For the time I am happy with just binding `isearch-filter-predicate` to something that calls `texmathp` but I understand that your solution is more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is a few years old, I think I might be able to contribute with one more answer.  Below is the code for a function called `math-hilite` which hides normal text and highlights everything in math style.  Moreover it sets a `read-only` property on hidden text and tells `isearch-filter-predicate` to ignore hidden text so that any further search or replacement is done only within math text.

With prefix argument `reverse`, math is hidden instead.

After you are done searching and replacing, call `math-hilite` once more to bring your buffer back to its normal state.

By redefining the variable `envir-bdry`,  all sorts of other non-TeX applications are possible.

```lisp
(require 'cl-lib)

(defun next-math-environment (start)
  "Assuming start is NOT inside a math environment, we return a
  list (b1 a1 a2 b2) with information regarding the next math
  environment after start: (buffer-substring a1 a2) is the
  environment itself, and (buffer-substring b1 b2) is the
  environment including the tokens marking the environment.
  If a math environment is malformed, that is, it
  extends beyond the end of the paragraph, then we report the end
  of the paragraph in both a2 and b2.  This function could be
  defined with texmathp, but it becomes much slower."
  (unless (boundp 'envir-bdry)
    (setq envir-bdry
      `(
        (,(regexp-quote "$$")                  . ,(regexp-quote "$$"))
        (,(regexp-quote "$")                   . ,(regexp-quote "$"))
        (,(regexp-quote "\\[")                 . ,(regexp-quote "\\]"))
        (,(regexp-quote "\\(")                 . ,(regexp-quote "\\)"))
        ("\\\\begin *{math}"                   . "\\\\end *{math}")
        ("\\\\begin *{align\\*?}"              . "\\\\end *{align\\*?}")
        ("\\\\begin *{gather\\*?}"             . "\\\\end *{gather\\*?}")
        ("\\\\begin *{equation}"               . "\\\\end *{equation}")
        ))
    (setq bdry-regexp (mapconcat (lambda (x) (format "\\(%s\\)" (car x))) envir-bdry "\\|")))
  (save-excursion (let (s paragraph-end
        (paragraph-start "\n[[:space:]]*\n"))
      (goto-char start)
      (when (search-forward-regexp bdry-regexp nil t)                                        ;; Search for the opening of a math environment
        (setq
          s (cl-loop for i from 1 if (match-string i) return (cdr (nth (1- i) envir-bdry)))  ;; s is the corresponding closing string
          paragraph-end (save-match-data (save-excursion (forward-paragraph) (point))))      ;; paragraph-end will bound the search for the closing string
        (append
            (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))                                         ;; First part of the output
            (if (search-forward-regexp s paragraph-end t)                                    ;; Search for the closing string
              (list (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))                                       ;; Last part of the output if closing string is found
              (list paragraph-end paragraph-end)))))))                                       ;; Malformed math environment. Cannot find end of environment whithin paragraph.
                                                                                             ;;   so return paragraph-end in last 2 slots

(defun math-hilite (&optional reverse)
  "Hide non-math TeX for purpose of searching and replacing,
  putting a 'read-only property on hiddent text.  If reverse is
  non-nil then hide math instead.  Call it a second time to cancel its effect"
  (interactive "P")
  (unless (boundp 'math-hid) (setq-local math-hid nil))                                     ;; This variable informs the state of the buffer
  (with-silent-modifications                                                                ;; Don't consider changing text properties as modifications
    (if (null math-hid)                                                                     ;; Buffer state is not altered.  Hide what must be hidden
      (let (nme
          text-state math-state
          (start (point-min))
          (hid (list 'face (cons 'foreground-color "grey20") 'read-only t))                 ;; Properties for hidden stuff
          (div (list 'face (cons 'foreground-color "salmon") 'read-only t))                 ;; Properties for separators
          )
        (setq-local
          math-hid t                                                                        ;; Set buffer as altered
          isearch-filter-predicate (lambda (x y) (null (get-text-property x 'read-only))))  ;; Set predicate for later search operations
        (if (null reverse )
          (setq text-state hid math-state nil)                                              ;; Hide normal text and show math (default)
          (setq text-state nil math-state hid)                                              ;; Hide math and show normal text
          )
        (font-lock-mode -1)
        (set-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) text-state)                            ;; Set whole buffer with text-state
        (while (setq nme (next-math-environment start))
          (set-text-properties (nth 0 nme) (nth 1 nme) div)                                 ;; Set opening boundary with div properties
          (set-text-properties (nth 1 nme) (nth 2 nme) math-state)                          ;; Set math environment with math-state
          (set-text-properties (nth 2 nme) (nth 3 nme) div)                                 ;; Set closing boundary with div properties
          (let ((stk (nth (if reverse 3 1) nme)))
            (put-text-property (1- stk) stk 'rear-nonsticky t))                             ;; Fix sticky issue
          (setq start (nth 3 nme)))                                                         ;; Get ready for seraching next math environment
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (search-forward-regexp "%" nil t)
            (set-text-properties (match-beginning 0) (line-end-position) hid))))            ;; Hide comments
      (set-text-properties (point-min) (point-max) nil)                                     ;; ELSE, when math-hid is t just reset everything
      (font-lock-mode 1)
      (setq-local isearch-filter-predicate 'isearch-filter-visible)
      (setq-local math-hid nil)
      )))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a built-in feature of `replace-regexp` and `query-replace-regexp` that allows you to do that with only a little typing: in the [replacement text](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html#index-back-reference_002c-in-regexp-replacement), you can use `\,` followed by a Lisp expression. Inside that expression, `\&` refers to the original text. Thus you can perform a conditional replacement by making the replacement text **`\,(if (WANT-TO-REPLACE) "MY REPLACEMENT" \&)`**.

Note that `(WANT-TO-REPLACE)` must not change the match data or the cursor position. If it changes the match data, wrap it in `save-match-data`. If it changes the point, wrap it in `save-excursion`.

For example, to replace `x` by `y` only in TeX math mode:

- Relying on LaTeX font lock, misses occurrences immediately before non-math-face end-math sequences like `\end{math}`: `x` → `\,(if (eq (face-at-point) 'font-latex-math-face) "y" \&)`
- Relying on LaTeX font lock: `x` → `\,(if (save-excursion (backward-char) (eq (face-at-point) 'font-latex-math-face)) "y" \&)`
- Relying on `texmathp`: `x` → `\,(if (save-match-data (texmathp)) "y" \&)`